# Segmentation fault in a function

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I want to find the address of an integer in an array. Debugger revealed that line 8 is at fault.
`if (*i==item) {ans=i;};`

Variable `ans` is local and not null, yet segmentation fault occurs.
Why is that and how can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* finder(int *begin, int *end, int item)
{
    int *ans=0; int *i=begin;

    while (i<end) {
        if (*i==item) {ans=i;};
        i++;
    }

    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    int arSize, target, i=0;
    int arr[10]={};
    int *first=&arr[0]; int *last; int *result;

    printf("Find element: ");
    scanf("&d",&target);
    printf("Array size: ");
    scanf("&d",&arSize);
    printf("Enter array: ");
    while (i<arSize){
        scanf("&d",&arr[i]);
        i++;
    }

    last=&arr[arSize];
    result=finder(first,last,target);

    printf("%s %p","Target's address is ",result);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ans` isn't the problem. It's more likely `i`. What is the value of `arSize`? Please tell us the exact inputs.

Comment: this should be  last=&arr[arSize-1]  ....

Comment: What if `arSize` is `10` or more than that ? If true then `last=&arr[arSize];` cause undefined behavior as you're going access array element out of bounds. B/w that `scanf("&d",&target);` --> `scanf("%d",&target);`

Comment: Why do you use `*ans` and not `ans`? You declare an array with this. If you also set it `NULL`. It seems that you do this multiple times.

Comment: Typo.  `scanf()` calls using `&` in format string, not `%`.  So the variables are not being read.  Since they are uninitialised when their values are being used, the code has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scanf()` format have typo: they use `'&'` instead of `'%`. As a result, the program (as posted) does not read any input.

**Suggestion**: make sure you get CLEAN compile (no warning, no errors) before trying to run (or debug). GCC flagged the format errors with the default 'cc'.

> ff.c:22:11: warning: too many arguments for format
>   [-Wformat-extra-args]
>
> ```
>  scanf("&d",&target);
>        ^~~~
> ```

3 fixes are needed.

- `scanf("&d",&target);`
- `scanf("&d",&arSize);`
- `scanf("&d",&arr[i]);`

For example:

```
    printf("Array size: ");
// BAD:    scanf("&d",&arSize);
    scanf("%d",&arSize);
```

Code seems to run fine on simple cases with this fix.

Comment: Also, never use `scanf()` (or other input functions) without confirming that it succeeded.  In this case a simple `if (scanf(...) != 1)` would have identified the error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it fails on the last iteration inside finder() in case the arSize is equal 10.

You declared an array 'arr[10]', so it means that the index of the last element is equal 9, not 10 :)

So, you should change one line in main():

```
last=&arr[arSize];
```

to:

```
last=&arr[arSize-1];
```

Of course, you should always check that arSize is <= 10.